# upload with content disposition android

Tags: android, upload, content-disposition

Here is my code to upload mp3

```
    builder= new StringBuilder(); 
    int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000;  // = 10 seconds
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    String urlString=base_url+"/api/greetings/phone/"+userExtensionData.getId();

    //System.out.println("urlString=== "+urlString);

    HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(urlString);
    try {



        httpPost.addHeader("app_token", userData.getAppToken());
        httpPost.addHeader("user_token",userData.getUserToken());
        httpPost.addHeader("user_ip",userData.getUserIpAddress());



          String BOUNDARY= "--eriksboundry--";

          httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+BOUNDARY);
           MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
           File file= new File(path);
           FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
           reqEntity.addPart("file",bin);
           reqEntity.addPart("greeting[name]", new StringBody("jdjd"));
           reqEntity.addPart("greeting[description]", new StringBody("dddvd"));




           httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

           httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);      


        HttpResponse response= httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        StatusLine statusLine =response.getStatusLine();

        statusCode=statusLine.getStatusCode();
        //System.out.println("status code === "+statusCode);
       if(statusCode ==200||statusCode ==500 ) {
            if(response!=null){
                HttpEntity entity= response.getEntity();
                InputStream content= entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                //System.out.println("submitted  ==  "+builder.toString());

            }
       }

    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
```

My problem is when i am trying to execute this i am getting 500 error and there is  a problem with content-disposition. 
  reqEntity.addPart("greeting[name]", new StringBody("jdjd"));
           reqEntity.addPart("greeting[description]", new StringBody("dddvd"));
i dont know how to add content-dispostion to multipart entity.
can anyone please help me out.
When i am trying to upload from advanced rest client its working 
enter image description [image: check here i am able to work out from rest client]

[image: but how to add content to that form check near payload]

i am not able to do the same from android code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MultipartyEntity` is deprecated. I suggest you go for it's alternative `MultipartEntityBuilder`

Here is the code for that

```
MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
reqEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
File file= new File(path);
FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
reqEntity.addPart("file",bin);
reqEntity.addPart("greeting[name]", new StringBody("jdjd"));
reqEntity.addPart("greeting[description]", new StringBody("dddvd"));
HttpEntity entity = reqEntity.build();
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: :no it doesnt work.my question i have to send this content--ARCFormBoundary76ntfhxhxxyldi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="greeting[name]"

yhgreetingrrgggddgdd
--ARCFormBoundary76ntfhxhxxyldi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="greeting[description]"

ddsss
--ARCFormBoundary76ntfhxhxxyldi--
 with file.how to add content disposition to multipart entity?.

Comment: you have written correct code to send contents with file. We add the content using addPart

Comment: if u check my 2 screenshot i have to fill that form and i have click on  raw tab and i should click on decode payload then it works.dont know how to execute in android.

Comment: BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                            .getEntity().getContent()));
                    String msg="";
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {
                        msg += line;
                    }
                    Log.i("msg=",""+msg);

Comment: Try this above code and tell me what message you get

Comment: exactly this  exception  I/System.out(17863): {"status":"error","errors":["Some error occured"]}

Comment: Can we decode this particular addpart reqEntity.addPart("greeting[name]", new StringBody("jdjd"));
reqEntity.addPart("greeting[description]", new StringBody("dddvd")); and i guess "[]" these characters should get decoded..isnt it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75678/discussion-between-exception-and-avinash-kanna).

Comment: :Hey we removed that decoding concept and updated with only uploading media file and passing data in addpart.its server side code problem not accepting addpart values.now its done and thank you very much.